# File Level Tracking In Git (Files from multiple branches in same directory)

Tags: git, directory, repository, latex, git-checkout

Is there any script that lets one remember branch/commit seperatly for files in some directory so that one can simultaneously work on file1 on branch1 and file2 on branch2 in the same directory and have them commit appropriately.  If not I'll implement it myself.

My plan is to have hidden checkout directories for various branches/repos and populating the apparent checkout with links to these files so that commits simply committed their respective hidden branches but advice would be appreciated.  Thus one could do something like

```
mgit checkout branch1 filename/filegroup
mgit add filename   (automatically to it's correct branch/repo)
mgit commit  (automatically to it's correct branch/repo)
```

Before anyone tells me this is a bad idea or incorrect use of version control consider the application:

So often when writing academic documents in TeX you end up with loosely related files that you wish to keep in version control. The problem is that these files are related and can benefit from the history/merging info git provides but often different versions of the files need to be selected independently.  Most commonly you simply want to work on variant1 of some paper while also working of variant2 of another but you also have situations where TeX combines several files so it's important to be able to put your choice of variants in the same folder.

In short you have a bunch of distinct files with distinct names which often derive from each other (thesis becomes paper), benefit from being in a single repo but it is unwieldy to have a dozen different checkouts to work on whatever versions of each file currently need attention.

Comment: It looks like you should split your repository. That way, you can have file1 on different branch than file2, because they will be in completely different repos.

Comment: I knew someone one was to say that and I explained why that can't work.  So I have something like 10 or twenty maybe more files that may be under work at one time.  It's simply unwiedly to have a directory for each file.

Worse I need to mix and match these files so tex can put together a presentation with variantA of header, variant B of section 1 etc.. so without massive pain I need them in the same directory since they may need to read the aux files produced by the other sections.

These are interelated files that need to have relative history preserved but the branch/repo is too coarse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think this is natively supported by git.
May be a local hook like a [pre-commit one](http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html) hook might try to check and checkout the right branch before allowing the commit to proceed.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough in the question.  I **know** it isn't natively supported by git.  I'm thinking of writing a script mgit on top of git to enable this functionality and wanted to check if any such script existed yet or if other people had better ideas than mine as to how to procede

Comment: Ohh and  no nothing like a pre-commit hook will work.  What needs to happen is that behind the scenes there is some mgit script that keeps track of the checked out files and which branches/repos they come from and then handle recommitting them appropriately.  In the background mgit would maintain a bunch of hidden git checkouts and link the files in the visible checkout to those.

Comment: @PeterGerdes: isn't it possible to have several clone of your repo, each one set one the right branch? Then you would work in a separate directory (not a git repo) filled with nothing else than symlinks. Symlinks to the right files in the right repos (ie the right branch). You modify any file from the central directory, and then go to each repo and add/commit what has actually been modified.

Comment: We still need a wrapper around it so you can commit and checkout files without manual uglyness.  This was my plan but I wanted to see if anyone else had written it first before I implemented it.

It still wouldn't. The problem is badly behaved text editors and other programs which delete your file and replace it with a brand new file containing the edits thus breaking your symlink.

The right solution is to keep a new index linking files to location in git tree.  We copy them back to appropriate checkout which also lets us minimize # of checkouts.

Comment: @PeterGerdes: interesting. If you come up with a viable script, you can post an answer here (and select your own answer as the official one)

Comment: I will...I asked one other quesiton first because I wanted some advice as to whether to do it through hidden repos or if there was direct git calls to make.