# Writing GIT Extension Allowing files in different branches/heads to coexist in same directory

Tags: git, directory, branch, git-checkout

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784825/file-level-tracking-in-git-files-from-multiple-branches-in-same-directory) I asked if anyone had already written a script to allow mixing files from multiple branches (or even repos) in the same directory so that they would all get committed/pulled/etc.. from their appropriate origins.

Please see that post for reasons why this isn't a case where splitting into separate repos or branch arrangement would work before objecting.

The answer to that question seems to be that no such script exists.  My question now is what is the best way to go about writing the script.

1) The easy way.  Wrap a simple perl script that checks multiple branches behind the scenes and keeps a record of which file belongs to which branch and simply copies the files back and executes the git commands behind the scenes.

2) If possible (I dunno) some kind of fancy usage of low level git commands to do this directly without having any checkouts.  Is this possible?

3) Some kind of low level interface into the git code.

The obvious problem with 2 is wasting resources with all the hidden checkouts and the ugliness of the whole thing but I don't know enough about 2 or 3 to know if they are reasonably possible.

--

I guess my primary question is whether there are low level git commands to check files into a branch without ever creating a checkout and to check them out into random directories.  If so I could just use these commands to directly work with the files in my multi-branch directory and avoid secret checkouts entierly.

Comment: Low level is the way to go.  I would imagine that the git suite of tools may add confusion.  The underlying means of git would definitely serve your purpose.  You don't need to work with the low level commands or the git code if you don't want to.  Answer to follow.

Answer (score 1):

[This chapter of the Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/7_raw_git.html) may be of interest to you for low-level Git interaction.

To paraphrase it,

1. Create blobs from your files with `git hash-object`.
2. Create a tree from your blobs with `git mktree`.
3. Create a commit for that tree with `git commit-tree`.
4. Update a branch to point to that commit with `git update-ref`.

Answer (score 0):

This is in essence what git-subtree does (it's a simple set of scripts) -- but it's non-trivial in cases of moving files between the boundaries. There's lots of things that it doesn't try to help with, but might well suffice if your use-case is sufficiently simple or well-disciplined.